# Trying to update a database attribute that is a primary key and also a foreign key to other tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Trying to update an attribute in COLUMN sname in SKILL table but it's not allowing me to because there are foreign keys CONSTRAINT in table SPOSSESSED and SREQUIRED.

These foreign keys are also stated as primary keys CONSTRAINT and therefore cannot be NULL. How do I go about with this?

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE SKILL(
sname         VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL, /* Skill name */
CONSTRAINT SKILL_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( sname ) );

CREATE TABLE SREQUIRED(
sname         VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL, /* Skill name*/
requires      VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL, /* Skill required*/
slevel        DECIMAL(2)      NOT NULL, /* Level required*/
CONSTRAINT SREQUIRED_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( sname, requires ),
CONSTRAINT SREQUIRED_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY ( sname) REFERENCES SKILL( sname ),
CONSTRAINT SREQUIRED_fkey2 FOREIGN KEY ( requires ) REFERENCES SKILL( sname ) );

CREATE TABLE SPOSSESSED(
anumber     DECIMAL(6)  NOT NULL, /* Applicant number*/
sname       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, /* Skill name*/
slevel      DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL, /* Skill level*/
CONSTRAINT SPOSSESSED_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( anumber, sname ), 
CONSTRAINT SPOSSESSED_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY ( anumber ) REFERENCES APPLICANT ( anumber ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT SPOSSESSED_fkey2 FOREIGN KEY ( sname )REFERENCES SKILL ( sname ),
CONSTRAINT SPOSSESSED_check1 CHECK ( slevel IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions

1. Create Id column in SKILL table and use that ID column in other tables as foreign key.
2. Add CASCADE ON UPDATE rule on foreign keys.

Comment: 3. Create the new skill. Copy data from old skill to new skill. Delete the old skill bottom-up.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much, Thorsten! I didn't even think of creating a new skill but only on renaming the skill.